# 32-bit to 64-bit conversion dll files

Tags: dll, 32bit-64bit, labview

I am working currently in Labview(64-bit) and want to connect a device that has a dll attached. This dll file is written in 32-bit, and now I encounter a problem with since 64-bit can't run the 32-bit.

So is there an option so I can execute the fil or any conversion of the 32-bit to 64-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't recompile the DLL to 64 bit or the vendor doesn't supply a 64 bit DLL there is no (easy) way.

The obvious easiest way for you would be to use Labview 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all of the entry points into the 32 bit DLL, you could create a sort of "in-process" server that is a stand-alone 32 bit app which loads the 32 bit DLL. Then you crate a 64 bit DLL that gets loaded into LabVIEW 64 which uses a method of inter-process communications to shuttle the data back and forth between the 32 bit and 64 bit processes. This is a clunky solution, but should work if all else fails.

Read the following article to learn how to create a .lib file for linking to the 32 bit DLL:

http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/